Reporting from Azure Sql in a customized app. SSRS vs Power BI
In the past (with sql server) when our team would want to provide reports to an end user we would create a web portal and incorporate SSRS and provide reports to any person who would have a valid username and password (authenticated via the db).
We are now creating a customized web app using Azure Sql, and we are researching our options for providing reports to the end user.  Power BI will be a bit of a challenge since we have internal and external users who will use the portal, and we want to have basic authentication via the database.  BI Embedded will be out of our price range.  Can we utilize SSRS with Azure as we have in the past with sql server?
